# Unable to create UNIQUE Filtered index with IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, duplication, unique-constraint, filtered-index

I have a table , in SQL Server 2012 enterprise edition, for which I want to have a unique index with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`, however I only want this index (and ignoring the duplicates) to apply only to a subset of the table - only rows with `FLAG = 1`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FOO]
([ID] NOT NULL,
[Value] [int] NULL,
[FLAG] [bit] NULL)
```

When trying to create the index using below query

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_UQ_FL_FOO_VALUE] ON [dbo].[FOO]
([Value] ASC)
WHERE [flag] = 1
WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
```

I get an error:

> Msg 10618, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot create filtered index 'IDX_UQ_FL_FOO_VALUE' on table 'dbo.FOO' because the statement sets the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option to ON. Rewrite the statement so that it does not use the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option.

Is it not possible to combine a filtered unique index with the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`?

Setting the index to non-unique is not an option. I need it to be unique to filter duplicate inserts, but only when inserting values with `FLAG = 1`. I need the insert of a duplicated row to be ignored, not to fail.

Comment: This is rather insane. Say I try to insert 5 rows with same `[Value]`, all with `FLAG=1`. You want the 4 rows to be ignored and only 1 row to succeed being inserted? And all these silently, without any warning or error? And which one of the 5 to be chosen to succeed? A random one of the 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869.aspx) the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option does not apply on filtered indexes:

> `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` cannot be set to ON for <sub>...</sub> filtered indexes.

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned by the [other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128561/6965), IGNORE_DUP_KEY is not supported for filtered indexes, which is explicitly [stated in the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx):

> Filtered indexes do not allow the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option.

There is a workaround, however, if you can afford a small change to the table's structure. With the help of a uniquifier column you can create a unique index that would effectively allow you to have unique `Value`s only for rows with `FLAG = 1`.

The following assumes that the ID column is already declared as unique (either being the primary key or having a UNIQUE constraint on it). First, add a computed column that would evaluate to NULL for the `FLAG = 1` rows and to `ID` for all the others:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.FOO
ADD Uniquifier AS CASE FLAG WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE ID END;
```

Now you can create a unique index on `(Value, Uniquifier)` with the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_1
ON dbo.FOO (Value, Uniquifier)
WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
```

Since `Uniquifier` will be NULL for rows with `FLAG = 1`, the uniqueness will be determined based on `Value` alone. All the other rows will be unique regardless of `Value` because `Uniquifier` is unique (since its value is taken from a unique column, `ID`).

A live demonstration of the method is available [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/529a9/1).

Comment: This is great, but also so dumb that this is the required solution.